# Linux 64bit NASM programs issues

Tags: linux, nasm

I have Linux Installed through VMware on my Win8 PC.I have written some codes in 64 bit NASM programming, that I can easily ececute on my college computers. But when I try to do the same in Linux on my PC, through the following command: **nasm  -f elf64 hex.asm** , it would give me "**unrecognised output format `elf64**'" error. Please suggest what is to be doon, asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very weird, because I am sure, that I have been using this output format many times without problems. It is also stated in the [NASM Doc](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html), that supported formats list includes `elf32`, `elf64` and `elfx32`.

You can try to execute `nasm -hf`. `-h` option causes `nasm` to execute immediately, after after giving a summary of its invocation options. Paired with `f` it will print all available formats.

But I would be very surprised, if `elf64` wasn't there.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mateusz. The version of linux I am using is Redhat LInux 5. I tried the command you mentioned, and it doesn't show the 64 bit for elf option. Its just 32. So is that my Nasm version is problematic or the Linux version? The version of nasm it shows is nasm i386 0.98.39-3.2.2.

Comment: On Ubuntu, for example, i386 binary (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/gutsy/i386/nasm/0.98.38-1.2build1) and amd64 binary (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/gutsy/amd64/nasm/0.98.38-1.2build1) are distinguished. I would be very surprised if RH is different in this matter. Your problem could be using 32bit binary of NASM. Try to install the newest version of 64bit NASM package. This may help.